# Proving that a linear transformation is onto

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $B= {v_1, v_2, ..., v_m}$ be a basis for $V$.
$B'= {w_1, w_2, ..., w_n}$ be a basis for $W$.

Define $f: Hom_F(V, W) \rightarrow M$, where $M$ is the set of all $m\times\,n$ matrices such that $f(T)= m(T)_{B,B'}$ for some $T \in Hom_F(V, W)$.

How will I prove that this function is onto?

Comment: This is a badly written sentence. $M=\{m\times n \text{ matrices } A: A=m(T)_{B,B'} \text{ for some } T\}$ and, separately, $f(T) = m(T)_{B,B'}$. Now it is clear that $f$ maps onto $M$ because you defined $M$ so that it would be.

Comment: Why is it already clear ? $M$ is only defined as the set of all $m \times\, n$ matrices?

Comment: Well, see, your sentence is really terrible. Note how I interpreted $M$.  But it's still OK. Given any $m\times n$ matrix, define the linear map $T$ by $[T(x)]_{B'} = A([x]_B)$.

Comment: I don't know what I should do next

Comment: I gave you the answer!! $[x]_B$ stands for the coordinate vector of $x\in V$ with respect to the basis $B$.

Comment: So $A$ is any $m \times\, n$ matrix?